# Looser throw specifier error in C++

Tags: c++, exception

The following code is generating the "Looser throw specifier error". Could you please help me to overcome this error?

```
class base
{
    virtual void abc() throw (exp1);
}

void base::abc() throw (exp1)
{
    ......
}

class sub : public base
{
    void abc() throw(exp1, exp2);
}

void sub::abc() throw (exp1, exp2)
{
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem comes about because the subclass must be usable wherever the base class can be used, and so must not throw any exception types other than those specified in the base class.

There are three solutions:

1. Modify the base class specifier to include every exception type that any subclass might ever need to throw
2. Modify every subclass to handle every exception type except those specified in the base class
3. Remove the exception specifiers.

I would suggest removing them; they are widely regarded as a bad idea, partly because of issues like this. As Matthieu points out, the Standard Committee agrees, and exception specifiers are due to be deprecated in the next version of the Standard.

Comment: In fact, they are deprecated in the new standard in favor of `noexcept`: that is either use `noexcept` to indicate that no exception can be thrown (equivalent of `throw()` but with no runtime diagnosis in case of violation of the contract) or don't use any specifier at all, which amounts to saying that the method can throw anything.

Comment: @Matthieu: "but with no runtime diagnosis in case of violation of the contract" - I thought it was going to `terminate` (15.4/9), has that changed since n3225?

Answer (score 6):

When you override a virtual method with a throw specifier in a derived class, the method in the derived class cannot throw more exceptions than the method in the superclass. If you were allowed to do this, you could break the contract created by the superclass's public API by overriding methods in a subclass.

In your example, you're saying that base::abc can only throw exp1. However, if you have a pointer of type base which is really pointing to an instance of sub, all of a sudden abc can throw exp2 in addition to exp1.

To fix the problem you need to remove exp2 from the throw specifier in the subclass or add exp2 to the throw specifier of the superclass.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose I try

```
base *b = new sub;
b->abc();
```

Based on the throw specifier in `base::abc`, I'd expect that it only throws `exp1`; but `sub::abc` says that it might also throw `exp2`.

If `sub::abc` can really throw `exp2`, then add `exp2` to the list of what `base::abc` can throw. If not, then remove it from `sub::abc`'s list.

And better: don't use throw specifiers. For more info, see [Can anyone explain C++ exception specifications to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761679/can-anyone-explain-c-exception-specifications-to-me) and http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm.