# Looser Throw Specifier in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

What does this error mean? How can I fix it? This is the header code that's causing it:

```
class BadJumbleException : public exception {
public:
    BadJumbleException (const string& msg); // Constructor, accepts a string as the message
    string& what();                         // Returns the message string
private:
    string message;                         // Stores the exception message
};
```

And this is the source code:

```
BadJumbleException::BadJumbleException (const string& m) : message(m) {}
string& BadJumbleException::what() { return message; }
```

EDIT: This is the error:

> looser throw specifier for 'virtual BadJumbleException::~BadJumbleException()

Comment: Did you post the error?

Comment: what needs to be declared not to throw anything.

Comment: @Flexo what do you mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looser throw specifier error in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269957/looser-throw-specifier-error-in-c)

Comment: Take a look at this SO article. [What the c++ standard says about loosing throw specifier in default destructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635464/what-the-c-standard-says-about-loosing-throw-specifier-in-default-destructor)

Comment: I looked at that question and none of the answers seem to apply to this code

Comment: I think that compiler means that throw specifiers are only for loosers.

Answer (score 29):

In C++03, per §18.6.1/5, `std::exception` has a destructor that is declared such that no exceptions can be thrown out of it ([a compilation error will be caused instead](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/764cd6fe3b72bc01)).

The language requires that when you derive from such a type, your own destructor must have the same restriction:

```
virtual BadJumbleException::~BadJumbleException() throw() {}
//                                                ^^^^^^^
```

This is because an overriding function may not have a *looser throw specification*.

---

In C++11, `std::exception::~exception` is *not* marked `throw()` (or `noexcept`) explicitly in the library code, but all destructors are `noexcept(true)` by default.

Since [that rule would include *your* destructor and allow your program to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6de19d2e196ce93a), this leads me to conclude that you are not *really* compiling as C++11.

Comment: In short, how is this error fixed? Why does this code work in some other projects, but not this one?

Comment: BTW how does a `throw()` specifier make sense on a destructor? You cannot throw exceptions anyway in destructors...

Comment: @MatteoItalia: In C++03, yes, you can. It terminates the program — at runtime. Hence `throw()` prevents you from falling into this nightmare in the first place. And, hence C++11 fixes the problem entirely.

Comment: @user2824889: I do not understand your question. Without knowing even the first thing about your "other projects", I cannot answer it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: You can, and there are good use cases for that. What you cannot have is a destructor that is executed as part of exception unwinding and throws.  A comment is not the right space for a long description, but there are use cases in fact :)