# Custom Exception in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create my own exception class but it is not working. Specifically, i am getting these errors:
    "looser throw specifier for 'virtual OversizeException::~OversizeException()'" 
    "overriding 'virtual std::exception::~exception() throw()'"
I'm relatively new to C++ so i would like some help!
Here is the the code

```
class OversizeException : public exception
{
private:    
    string message = " ";

public:
    OverlapTilesException()
    {
         message = " Cannot put ship there! Oversize Exception";
    }
    const string what()
    {
        return message;
    }
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698653/looser-throw-specifier-in-c

Comment: Sorry i didn't see that it was already answered.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You have some typos:

- constructor name mismatch
- signature of `what` mismatch (`override` helps to spot those issues).

Your code should be:

```
class OversizeException : public std::exception
{
private:    
    std::string message = " ";

public:
    OversizeException()
    {
         message = " Cannot put ship there! Oversize Exception";
    }
    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return message.c_str();
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07b3150c41bfd7a3)

Comment: Sorry about the typos :) but i still shows the same error.. Thanks though i think i found the answer from another post :)

Comment: Just added [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07b3150c41bfd7a3) link. No errors.